# Node JS: single quotes JSON object at client side

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs, jsonparser

When i try to read JSON Object at the client side, defined as

```json
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5db5d04d3ce189bbc7231dc1"),
  "att_member": [
    {
      "text": " It's a joke",
      "date": ISODate("2019-10-27T17:13:49.509Z"),
    }
  ]
}
```

The error while doing parsing is due to presence of single quotes. 

 how to resolve this error

```js
<script>
    var data1=JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(tag) %>');
</script>
```

```js
<script>
    var data1=JSON.parse('{"att_member":[{"text":" false, myth's, not true","date":"2019-10-27T17:13:49.509Z"...]..}
</script>
```

*'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list'*

Comment: Use code formatting next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either escape the single quotes in your JSON by using a backlash before it or you can use backticks (`) as your quotes which creates a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), but that's not too different than a regular one.

```
let escaped = '{"text": "false, myth\'s"}';

let backtick = `{"text": "false, myth's"}`;
```